# How to parse "2022-02-04T12:20:47,398000+01" into SimpleDateFormat?

Tags: android, simpledateformat

My date string looks like this **"2022-02-04T12:20:47,398000+01"**.

I tried this format `SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss,SSSSSSZ")` but it throws an exception.

Minimum API level that I need to support is 23, so I can't use 'X' symbols in the format like `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss,SSSSSSX"`.

Is there a safe way to parse the date string I have on android?

Comment: what is +01 at end of your string date?

Comment: Consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends. See if you either can use [desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) or add [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project, in order to use java.time, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Comment: [Code using java.time](http://tpcg.io/PXNSVY).

Comment: @behrad `+01` is an offset, 1 hour ahead of UTC, as used for example in Europe/Stockholm time zone in February. BTW the format is [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

Answer (score 0):

use the following

```
String inputDate = "2022-02-04T12:20:47,398000+01";
            String result;

            SimpleDateFormat inputformat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
            SimpleDateFormat outputformat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.ENGLISH);
            try {
                Date convertDate  = inputformat.parse(inputDate);

                result = outputformat.format(convertDate);
                tvResult.setText(result);
            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: That gives the wrong result. You are neither parsing the microseconds (giving an error of 0.398 seconds) nor the UTC offset (giving an error of up to at least 13 hours).